# Gaussian Processes Regression with multiple input frequencies

Tags: regression, machine-learning

Is it possible to perform Gaussian Processes Regression with inputs with different frequencies, e.g. one data vector $x_1$ with daily measurements and one vector $x_2$ with monthly measurements?